# AWS route table point default to network interface in a different subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routing, nat, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to setup an EC2 instance as NAT gateway of sorts that other instances in a private network will be routed to.

I have a following setup:

**VPC**

- 10.0.0.0/16

**2 subnets**

- A: 10.0.1.0/24
- B: 10.0.2.0/24

**2 EC2 instances**

- NAT instance with 2 network interfaces eth0, eth1, both in subnet A
- Another instance in subnet B

In the NAT instance, eth0 is meant for public network and eth1 for private and they have firewalls set accordingly.

I tried to create route table for subnet B that routes the default to eth1 of NAT, i.e.:

```
0.0.0.0/0         <id of eth1 on NAT>
```

Then I tried to run `tshark -i eth1` (Wireshark in command line) on NAT to see if any traffic is getting there and I ran `ping google.com` on the other instance. With no success. I also tried `curl google.com` just in case pings are blocked somewhere, but also nothing happened.

Looks like there is something wrong with the way AWS is routing the traffic so it never reaches the network interface even though the route table is set that way.

I'd appreciate if someone can help me with this. Thank you.

*DISCLAIMER: I know that AWS has a built-in NAT gateway option and it's not suitable for my case.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As neither the source nor the destination of the packets are an IP address that belongs to your *NAT gateway of sorts*, you need to disable the *srcdst check* on the Network Interfaces you'd like to handle traffic (I'd say both in the NAT gateway):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#change_source_dest_check

Otherwise the platform drops the traffic as an "antispoofing" protection so to speak.

If you want to do this in Azure, the equivalent is the [IP Forwarding flag](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-create-route-table-portal).

Comment: omg I read all the relevant docs but never would I think of something like this. Thank you so much!! It works!